# Can you breed two emerald dragons?

Tags: dragonvale

I've got an emerald dragon and am now waiting for a second one to come. I don't really care for the gems so I wonder whether I should display the second one as egg or hatch it and breed the third one from two previous ones.

Answer (score 1):

No, **Emerald Dragons cannot breed,** even with each other. From the [Dragonvale wiki on the Emerald Dragon:](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Emerald_Dragon)

> The Emerald Dragon can ONLY be bred by selecting a Crystal Dragon to mate with a Lichen Dragon at the Breeding Cave/Epic Breeding Island.

Also note that there will be 12 gem dragons, one for each month. I'd recommend keeping the egg as a showcase, as eventually you'll end up with 1 of each gem dragon if you play enough.